# Where is my logic going wrong which involves multiplying by two and subtracting by one to obtain a given number?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

http://codeforces.com/contest/520/problem/B

Vasya has found a strange device. On the front panel of a device there are: a red button, a blue button and a display showing some positive integer. After clicking the red button, device multiplies the displayed number by two. After clicking the blue button, device subtracts one from the number on the display. If at some point the number stops being positive, the device breaks down. The display can show arbitrarily large numbers. Initially, the display shows number n.

Bob wants to get number m on the display. What minimum number of clicks he has to make in order to achieve this result?

Input
The first and the only line of the input contains two distinct integers n and m (1 ≤ n, m ≤ 10^4), separated by a space .

Output
Print a single number — the minimum number of times one needs to push the button required to get the number m out of number n.

I developed the following recursive solution. I know it will time out, but I will memoise it, and that will get my solution accepted. But as of now, I am getting a wrong answer in one of the inputs.

My code is:

```
int func (int n, int m);
int main (void)
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    int count = func(n,m);
    cout<<count<<"\n";
    return 0;
}

int func (int n, int m)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return INT_MAX; // this should be because we can never go to some 
                        // other digit if we are at 0
    if (n == m)
        return 0;
    else if (2*n == m || n == m+1)
        return 1;
    else if (n > m)
        return func(n-1,m)+1;
    else 
        return min(func(n-1,m),func(n*2,m))+1;
}
```

Now, when I enter the input as `(1,3)`, my code shows Segmentation fault. I tried to debug it, and I found out that it sorts of go in an infinite loop because of which I get the Seg fault. However, I want to know, then how should I make the logic for this? What will be the recursive function for this? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if `n` is zero?

Comment: @greybeard, it should return INT_MAX because we won't be able to go to some other digit if the existing digit is 0. (Edited in my code) but the answer still is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

The SEG fault is due to calculating doing INT_MAX+1.

Actually I think this problem is better solved working this way.

- For all cases n>m, the shortest count is n-m.

  ```
  if (n<m)
      return n-m;
  ```
- For all cases n==m, the shortest count is 0.

  ```
  else if (n==m)
      return 0;
  ```
- For all cases n < m, the shortest count can be calculated as:

  ```
  let sequence Y= [(m/(2^1), m/(2^2), ... 1]  // use the ceiling values
  find X is the next number in the Y where n >= X.
  return func(X*2) + n-X + 1;
  ```

For n = 57, m = 201, then Y = [101, 51, 26, 13, 7, 4, 2, 1], X would be 51.
So the answer can be calculated as

```
 (57-51)+1 = 7 steps, result now 51*2 = 102
 (102-101)+1 = 2 steps, result now 101*2 = 202
 (202-201) = 1 steps
 =====> Total steps 10
```

For n = 4, m = 6, then Y = [3, 2, 1], X would be 3.
So the answer can be calculated as

```
 (4-3)+1 = 2 steps, result now 3*2=6
 =====> Total steps 2
```

For n = 1, m = 3, then Y = [2, 1], X would be 1.
So the answer can be calculated as

```
 already in Y= 1 steps, result now 1*2 = 2
 already in Y= 1 steps, result now 2*2 = 4
 (4-3) = 1 step
 =====> Total steps 3
```

Notice you can precalcuate Y before entering your function and pass it in so you don't have to recompute each time.

Comment: I tried to add the condition if `n==0` by returning INT_MAX. But it still shows a seg fault. And then, what will be the correct recursion for this? Thanks!

Comment: your solution won't work on the case when the input is `(4,6)`. According to you, the answer will be `3` but the correct answer is `2`. Because we can decrement `4` by `1` and multiply it by `2` which will give us the correct answer, which makes the number of operations to be only 2.

Comment: your latest edit gives a segfault on the input as `(4,6)`.

Comment: the latest answer gives INT_MAX as answer on `(4,6)`.

Comment: your latest modifications give a seg fault on giving the input as `(1,3)`. This was the same problem I had in my original code.

Comment: I will try and code that. But how do I come up with that? I mean you yourself tried so many different conditions, but none of them worked. How did you come up on this then? What was your approach on coming to this?

Comment: You should just be able to translate all my pseudocode into lines of code directly.  I realized there were multiple cases where recursion was being done on the same values.  If you try and exhaust all possibilities, it may never end.  For instance, if n = 4, then it might try 3, then 2, then 4, then 3, then 2.. you need a way to clearly end it.  This specific problem is simple enough to solve without recursion (or any at all) just by working it out on paper and seeing what is happening at each layer of the stack.